# Python Pandas Merge Two DataFrames With Conditional Logic

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Supposed I have two `pandas DataFrame`s as follows,

`df_actual`

```
ID  NAME    PRODUCT CHANNEL ACTUAL
1   A       W       G       233
1   A       W       M       4
1   A       X       G       188
1   A       X       M       4
1   A       Y       G       37
1   A       Y       M       4
1   A       Z       G       272
1   A       Z       M       4
```

and `df_target`

```
ID  NAME    PRODUCT TARGET
1   A       W       289
1   A       X       253
1   A       Y       36
1   A       Z       334
```

I am expecting to get the result as follows,

```
ID  NAME    PRODUCT CHANNEL ACTUAL  TARGET  
1   A       W       G       233     284     <<< 289 * (233/(233+4))
1   A       W       G       4       5       <<< 289 * (4/(233+4))
1   A       X       G       188     248     <<< 253 * (188/(248+5))
1   A       X       G       4       5       <<< 253 * (4/(248+5))
1   A       Y       M       37      32      …
1   A       Y       M       4       4       …
1   A       Z       M       272     329     …
1   A       Z       M       4       5       …
```

So basically what I want to do, adding a new column to the `df_actual` called `TARGET`. In order to compute the values within the column `TARGET`,

1. I have to get the `ACTUAL` values in `df_actual` for certain `ID`, `NAME`, `PRODUCT`, and `CHANNEL`, and then get the `TARGET` value in `df_target` for the same `ID`, `NAME`, and `PRODUCT` as before.
2. Then compute the new `TARGET` values for each `CHANNEL` using the contribution of each `CHANNEL` to the total `CHANNEL` for certain `ID`, `NAME`, and `PRODUCT`.

For example, to get the new `TARGET` values for `ID` 1, `NAME` A, `PRODUCT` W, and `CHANNEL` G, I need to use this formula 289 * (233 / (233 + 4)).

- 289 comes from the `TARGET` value in `df_target`.
- 233 comes from the `ACTUAL` value in `df_actual` for `CHANNEL` G
- 4 comes from the `ACTUAL` value in `df_actual` for `CHANNEL` M

My real data is quite huge, more than 1 Mio rows. So if you can suggest the vectorize solution, I will be very thankful. Nevertheless, any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following vectorized approach:

```
In [39]: m = df_actual.merge(df_target)

In [40]: m
Out[40]:
   ID NAME PRODUCT CHANNEL  ACTUAL  TARGET
0   1    A       W       G     233     289
1   1    A       W       M       4     289
2   1    A       X       G     188     253
3   1    A       X       M       4     253
4   1    A       Y       G      37      36
5   1    A       Y       M       4      36
6   1    A       Z       G     272     334
7   1    A       Z       M       4     334

In [41]: m['TARGET'] = (m.TARGET * m.ACTUAL / m.groupby(['NAME','PRODUCT'])['ACTUAL'].transform('sum')).round()

In [42]: m
Out[42]:
   ID NAME PRODUCT CHANNEL  ACTUAL  TARGET
0   1    A       W       G     233   284.0
1   1    A       W       M       4     5.0
2   1    A       X       G     188   248.0
3   1    A       X       M       4     5.0
4   1    A       Y       G      37    32.0
5   1    A       Y       M       4     4.0
6   1    A       Z       G     272   329.0
7   1    A       Z       M       4     5.0
```

Comment: Nice solution ;)

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I am looking for. Neat, elegant, and fast! Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @arnold, glad i could help :-)